# Pixel buds pro volume controls and in-ear detection not working

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 23.04

Might be a trivial issue but I wonder why the in-ear detection and volume controls do not work on Ubuntu 23.04?

Only play/pause controls are working. Is this a Bluetooth driver issue? Software specific? or something to do with the buds themselves?

They work perfectly on android and Windows on the same laptop.